# Ban a user and end their session

Tags: users, session

I'm working on a plugin derived from this [tutorial](http://www.wpexplorer.com/how-to-ban-a-wordpress-user/). So far, the plugin adds a checkbox on a user's profile edit page where admins can ban the user.

[image: checkbox]

If checked, the user will receive a message upon logging in:

[image: banned]

It works fine. The problem is, if the user is already logged in (has an active session) and gets banned, the user can continue to interact with the site **until** either the session ends or the user logs out.

**How do I end the user's session upon banning so the user is forced out?**

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Admin init
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_admin_init(){

    // Edit user profile
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'rc_edit_user_profile' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'rc_edit_user_profile_update' );

}
add_action('admin_init', 'rc_admin_init' );


/**
 * Adds custom checkbox to user edition page
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_edit_user_profile() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $user_id;

    // User cannot disable itself
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    if ( $current_user_id == $user_id ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <h3>Ban user</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td><label for="rc_ban"><input name="rc_ban" type="checkbox" id="rc_ban"  /> Check to ban user.</label></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}


/**
 * Save custom checkbox
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_edit_user_profile_update() {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $user_id;

    // User cannot disable itself
    $current_user    = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    if ( $current_user_id == $user_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Lock
    if( isset( $_POST['rc_ban'] ) && $_POST['rc_ban'] = 'on' ) {
        rc_ban_user( $user_id );
    } else { // Unlock
        rc_unban_user( $user_id );
    }

}


/**
 * Ban user
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_ban_user( $user_id ) {

    $old_status = rc_is_user_banned( $user_id );

    // Update status
    if ( !$old_status ) {
        update_user_option( $user_id, 'rc_banned', true, false );
    }
}


/**
 * Un-ban user
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_unban_user( $user_id ) {

    $old_status = rc_is_user_banned( $user_id );

    // Update status
    if ( $old_status ) {
        update_user_option( $user_id, 'rc_banned', false, false );
    }
}


/**
 * Checks if a user is already banned
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_is_user_banned( $user_id ) {
    return get_user_option( 'rc_banned', $user_id, false );
}


/**
 * Check if user is locked while login process
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_authenticate_user( $user ) {

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        return $user;
    }

    // Return error if user account is banned
    $banned = get_user_option( 'rc_banned', $user->ID, false );
    if ( $banned ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rc_banned', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: This user account is disabled.', 'rc') );
    }

    return $user;
}

add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'rc_authenticate_user', 1 );
```

So the ending of the session should go in the `rc_ban_user()` function.

**EDIT**: Full plugin posted [below](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124884/24875).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `wp_logout()`. It calls `wp_clear_auth_cookie()` and invalidates the current log-in information immediately.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_action( 'init', 'log_out_banned_user' );

function log_out_banned_user() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( ! get_user_option( 'rc_banned', $user->ID, false ) )
        return;

    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Just a small remark to your (absolutely correct) answer: The user will still be logged in for that pageview as `init` hooks after the user authentification. To be totally safe you could add a redirect to the end of your function.

Comment: @s1lv3r Good point. I have extended my example.

Comment: @toscho Confirming that this code works great! I will post the full plugin once it is ready. One question, will this solution affect performance much?

Comment: @ChristineCooper Depends on the amount of your users and on the database indexes. Meta queries are slow sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

While toscho's method works, a simpler approach might be to use the `authenticate` hook to prevent them from authenticating via cookie, or any other means, in a more direct fashion.

Totally untested code. Should work though.

```
// the priority of 999 is to ensure it's last in the auth chain
add_filter('authenticate', 'force_fail_banned_users', 999, 3); 

function force_fail_banned_users($user, $username, $password) {
    if ( ! is_a($user, 'WP_User') ) { 
        // we only care about actual users who already auth'd okay via some means
        return $user; 
    }

    if ( rc_is_user_banned( $user->ID ) ) {
        // user is banned, so return a failure case
        return new WP_Error('banned_user', 'Banned message goes here.');
    }

    // user not banned, so return the user normally
    return $user;
}
```

The authenticate filter chain lets you decide whether or not a user is authenticated at every possible opportunity for them to authenticate. Returning a value WP_User logs them in. Returning a WP_Error of any sort fails their authentication attempt, no matter how it was done, whether via username/password or via cookie.

Comment: +1 but be wary on the filter's priority. The internal WP functions don't check if $user already is a WP_Error, meaning you want to check *after* they're all done — priority 31 or higher.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I set it to 999.

Comment: @Otto I tested this code without success, user can continue to browse the site. Do you by any chance know where the issue lies to make it function? Also, is this a better solution compared to toscho's working code when considering server performance etc?

Comment: This won't block them from "browsing the site", it will block them from authenticating or logging in. If you want to block viewing of any kind, that's a whole different thing.

Answer (score 2):

I also write similar plugin and already published it on WordPress.org. I think the best solution drop user session immediately then administrator click "ban" (block) button (link). This possible with `WP_Session_Tokens` class:

```
$manager = \WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );
$manager->destroy_all();
```

And even if user currently authorised and some pages from `/wp-admin/` opened they will be force log out because we already drop sessions (immediately).

Source code: https://wordpress.org/plugins/mark-user-as-spammer/

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is now ready to be used and functions elegantly. Thanks to **Remi** for the original tutorial and **toscho** (the bot) for the working solution to end users session upon banning.

### Future Updates

I plan the following for future updates:

- Option to delete a user's comments or/and posts upon banning.
- Add a custom ban message for specific user.
- Allow admins to ban multiple users on users listing page in wp-admin.

Leave a comment if you have any update suggestions. I will edit this answer whenever there are any updates to the plugin.

### Ban Users Plugin

Create a folder named `ban-users` in your plugin folder and create a file named `ban-users.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Ban Users
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123902/ban-a-user-and-end-their-session
Description: Allows you to ban users
Author: Christine Cooper, Remi, toscho
Version: 1.1
Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123902/ban-a-user-and-end-their-session
*/


/**
 * Admin init
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_admin_init(){

    // Edit user profile
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'rc_edit_user_profile' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'rc_edit_user_profile_update' );

}
add_action('admin_init', 'rc_admin_init' );


/**
 * Adds custom checkbox to user edition page
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_edit_user_profile() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $user_id;

    // User cannot disable itself
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    if ( $current_user_id == $user_id ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <h3>Ban User</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td><label for="rc_ban"><input name="rc_ban" type="checkbox" id="rc_ban" <?php if ( get_user_option( 'rc_banned', $user_id, false ) ) { echo 'checked'; } ?> /> Check to ban user </label></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}


/**
 * Save custom checkbox
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_edit_user_profile_update() {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $user_id;

    // User cannot disable itself
    $current_user    = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    if ( $current_user_id == $user_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Lock
    if( isset( $_POST['rc_ban'] ) && $_POST['rc_ban'] = 'on' ) {
        rc_ban_user( $user_id );
    } else { // Unlock
        rc_unban_user( $user_id );
    }

}


/**
 * Ban user
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_ban_user( $user_id ) {

    $old_status = rc_is_user_banned( $user_id );

    // Update status
    if ( !$old_status ) {
        update_user_option( $user_id, 'rc_banned', true, false );
    }
}


/**
 * Un-ban user
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_unban_user( $user_id ) {

    $old_status = rc_is_user_banned( $user_id );

    // Update status
    if ( $old_status ) {
        update_user_option( $user_id, 'rc_banned', false, false );
    }
}


/**
 * Checks if a user is already banned
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_is_user_banned( $user_id ) {
    return get_user_option( 'rc_banned', $user_id, false );
}



/**
 * End a users active session if they are banned
 * By toscho http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123903/24875
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.1 
 * @return      void
*/
add_action( 'init', 'log_out_banned_user' );

function log_out_banned_user() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( ! get_user_option( 'rc_banned', $user->ID, false ) )
        return;

    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) );
    exit;
}



/**
 * Check if user is locked while login process
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0 
 * @return      void
*/
function rc_authenticate_user( $user ) {

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        return $user;
    }

    // Return error if user account is banned
    $banned = get_user_option( 'rc_banned', $user->ID, false );
    if ( $banned ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rc_banned', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Your user account has been disabled.', 'rc') );
    }

    return $user;
}

add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'rc_authenticate_user', 1 );
```